# How to display a Firebase list in REAL TIME?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a TODO List function (Alarmas), but I feel I'm not taking advantage of Firebase's Realtime features enough.

The Widget displays the list very well, however when someone puts a new task from another cell phone, I am not being able to show it automatically, but I must call the build again by clicking on the "TODO button" in the BottomNavigationBar.

Is there a way that the new tasks are automatically displayed without doing anything?

I'm using streams to get the list...

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    alarmaBloc.cargarAlarmas();

///---Scaffold and others

return StreamBuilder(
          stream: alarmaBloc.alarmasStream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AlarmaModel>> snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final tareasList = snapshot.data;
              if (tareasList.length == 0) return _imagenInicial(context);
            
              return ListView(

                children: [
                  for (var itemPendiente in tareasList)
                    _crearItem(context, alarmaBloc, itemPendiente),
                  //more widgets
                  ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            } 
              return Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('Preloader.gif'), height: 200.0,));
          },
      ),
```

And, I read the Firebase Data in this way...

```
Future<List<AlarmaModel>> cargarAlarmas() async {

  final List<AlarmaModel> alarmaList = new List(); 

  Query resp = db.child('alarmas');

  resp.onChildAdded.forEach((element) {
        
        final temp = AlarmaModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(element.snapshot.value));
        temp.idAlarma = element.snapshot.key;
        alarmaList.add(temp);    // element.snapshot.value.
  });

  await resp.once().then((snapshot) {
    print("Total list was loaded - ${alarmaList.length}");
  }); //I'm using this await to be sure that the full list was loaded, so I can order and process it later

      return alarmaList;

}
```

How can I display a List from Firebase in "true" Real Time?

Comment: Q: What is your client?  An Android handset?  "Something else"?

Answer (score 1):

To properly manage the state of asynchronously loaded data, you should:

1. Start loading/listening to the data in `initState()`
2. Set the data into the state (with `setState()`) when you receive it or it is updated.
3. Then render it from the state in the `build` method.

So in your code that'd be something like:

```
final List<AlarmaModel> alarmaList = new List();  // this is now a field in the `State` object

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  Query resp = db.child('alarmas');

  resp.onChildAdded.forEach((element) {
        final temp = AlarmaModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(element.snapshot.value));
        temp.idAlarma = element.snapshot.key;
        alarmaList.add(temp);

        setState(() {
          alarmaList = alarmaList;
        })
  });

}
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///---Scaffold and others

    return StreamBuilder(
          stream: alarmaBloc.alarmasStream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AlarmaModel>> snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final tareasList = snapshot.data;
```

If you only want to repaint once you've gotten a complete update from the database, you can put the call to `setState()` in a `value` listener, just use `onValue` in that instead of `once()`, as you also want to catch the updates.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Q: What kind of client(s) would this kind of app typically be deployed on?

Comment: A mobile one (Android in my case)

Comment: Hi puf. I couldn't fix it. I'm using BLOC and Provider Pattern, then I started loading in the initstate of my stateful widget. @override
void initState() { 
  super.initState();
  alarmaBloc.cargarAlarmas();
  setState(() {alarmaList = alarmaList;}); I deleted the once() in my provider.  The widget works fine, but the real time effect didn't work. I can't add a setstate in my provider.

Comment: Hey @puf. I included a future in my stateful widget to do a reference to alarmaList, but it doesn't work yet.     
        `Future<List<AlarmaModel>> alarmaList; 

override
void initState() { 
  super.initState();
  alarmaList = alarmaBloc.cargarAlarmas();
  setState(() {alarmaList = alarmaList;});
}`  How can I implement a solution when I'm using BLOC and Provider pattern?

Comment: I haven't used BLoCs mysef, but I expect you'll need to expose the stream from the blog to your widget.

Comment: @puf Yep. I'm exposing the stream from there and the BLoC is calling my provider. In Provider I have the query section `resp.onChildAdded` that you specify (`cargarAlarmas()`). It returns a Future of an AlarmaModel List (we could call it alarmaList)