# How to display a Firebase list in REAL TIME using BLoC Pattern?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, bloc, rxdart

I have a TODO List function (Alarmas), but I feel I'm not taking advantage of Firebase's Realtime features enough.

The Widget displays the list very well, however when someone puts a new task from another cell phone, I am not being able to show it automatically, but I must call the build again by clicking on the "TODO button" in the BottomNavigationBar.

Is there a way that the new tasks are automatically displayed without doing anything?

I'm using BLOC Pattern and Provider to get Data through Streams...

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    alarmaBloc.cargarAlarmas();

///---Scaffold and others

return StreamBuilder(
          stream: alarmaBloc.alarmasStream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AlarmaModel>> snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final tareasList = snapshot.data;
              if (tareasList.length == 0) return _imagenInicial(context);
            
              return ListView(

            children: [
              for (var itemPendiente in tareasList)
                _crearItem(context, alarmaBloc, itemPendiente),
              //more widgets
              ],
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        } 
          return Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('Preloader.gif'), height: 200.0,));
      },
  ),
```

@puf published a solution in [How to display a Firebase list in REAL TIME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64507561/how-to-display-a-firebase-list-in-real-time) using setState, but I don't know how to implement it because I can't use setState inside my BLoC pattern page.

## UPDATE

My BLoC Pattern looks like this...

```
class AlarmaBloc {

  final _alarmaController = new BehaviorSubject<List<AlarmaModel>>();
  final _alarmaProvider = new AlarmaProvider();


  Stream <List<AlarmaModel>>    get alarmasStream     => _alarmaController.stream;

  Future<List<AlarmaModel>> cargarAlarmas() async {
    final alarmas = await _alarmaProvider.cargarAlarmas();
    _alarmaController.sink.add(alarmas);
    return alarmas;
  }

 //---

  dispose() {
    _alarmaController?.close();
  }
```

And my PROVIDER looks like this...

```
  Future<List<AlarmaModel>> cargarAlarmas() async {

  final List<AlarmaModel> alarmaList = new List(); 

  Query resp = db.child('alarmas');

  resp.onChildAdded.forEach((element) {
        print('Provider - Nuevo onChild Alarma ${element.snapshot.value['fecha']} - ${element.snapshot.value['nombreRefEstanque']} - ${element.snapshot.value['pesoPromedio']}}');
        final temp = AlarmaModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(element.snapshot.value));
        temp.idAlarma = element.snapshot.key;
        alarmaList.add(temp);    // element.snapshot.value.
  });
  await resp.once().then((snapshot) {
    print("Las Alarmas se cargaron totalmente - ${alarmaList.length}");
  });

      return alarmaList;
```

How can I display a List from Firebase in "true" Real Time using BLoC Pattern?

Comment: you can attach a "listener" using firebase `firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount').on('value', function(snapshot) { clickTODO();});` as shown from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: In a BLoC you'll need to expose a stream with the same information to the view.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. I included an update with the class that contains my BLoC pattern that expose a stream and also the Provider query function.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Not quite, I implemented a workaround to get Realtime